# ADD 1 SEC to date in a column of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**using sql server 2008**

i have date something like this,

```
2016-05-11 13:17:41.410
```

can i remove millisecond and add 1 sec

will look like this.

```
2016-05-11 13:17:42
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this ?

Comment: @Squirrel: applying SCD-2 so user want to see to_date of history record closed 1 second earlier than active records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @dt datetime = '2016-05-11 13:17:41.410'

select  @dt, dateadd(MILLISECOND, 1000 - datepart(MILLISECOND, @dt), @dt)
```

Comment: Thanks : this is giving +1 sec, will it be possible to get -1 sec. Kindly help

Comment: just change from `1000` to `-1000`

Comment: Thanks : this is giving +1 sec, will it be possible to get -1 sec. also , so i can have three value, 1,+1,-1 Kindly help

Comment: you mean in 2 separate column ? one is +1 sec, one is -1 sec ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @input DATETIME = '2016-05-11 13:17:41.410'

SELECT DATEADD(ms, -1 * DATEPART(ms,@input), DATEADD(s, 1, @input))
```